# AutoSuggest from a array

Tags: javascript, autosuggest

I have a php script which generates JS array in this form

```
new Array(

    new Array("Maine", 1), 

    new Array("Maryland", 2), 

    new Array("Massachusetts", 3), 

    new Array("Michigan", 4), 

    new Array("Minnesota", 5), 

    new Array("Mississippi", 6), 

    new Array("Missouri", 7), 

    new Array("Montana", 8)

);
```

can some one please suggest , how to implement a Auto Suggestion for the search form ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jQuery UI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data):

> Autocomplete can be customized to work
>   with various data sources, by just
>   specifying the source option. A data
>   source can be:
>
> - an Array with local data
> - a String, specifying a URL
> - a Callback
>
> The local data can be a simple Array of Strings,
>   or it contains Objects for each item
>   in the array, with either a label or
>   value property or both. The label
>   property is displayed in the
>   suggestion menu. The value will be
>   inserted into the input element after
>   the user selected something from the
>   menu. If just one property is
>   specified, it will be used for both,
>   eg. if you provide only
>   value-properties, the value will also
>   be used as the label.